# Issue with simple python API in flask. Trying to create a post method to add json data to a list

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a simple flask api to post json data to a list (eventually with be redshift but this is just a simple test program).

I have attached the api code first followed by the code to send data.

I am getting internal server error issues when running the second script.

The code seems very simple though and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

audit_log = []
class audit(Resource):
    #def get (self):
     #return {"data":"HelloWorld"}

    def put (self):
        new_item = request.get_json()
        audit_log.append(new_item)
        return new_item

api.add_resource(audit,"/")

app.run()
```

```
import requests

BASE = "HTTP://127.0.0.1:5000/"

response = requests.put(BASE, params = {'auditid' : 'xyz', 'jobname' : 'abc'})

print (response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't imported the Flask properly

instead of this

```
from flask import request
```

use this

```
from flask import Flask, request
```

This should work fine...